# viewmodel is being set between screen navigations with composable

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android

I have a small cart system. I want to maintain items added to the cart and for the person they are added for across screens.

But by the time i reach screen2, the viewmodel resets.

```
@HiltViewModel
class CartVM
    @Inject
    constructor() : ViewModel() {
        private var orderInformation: OrderInformation by mutableStateOf(OrderInformation())
            

  fun submitOrder() { }

  fun getAllCartItems(): List<BasketItem> {
            return orderInformation.cartItems.value
        }

  fun addItemToCart(basketItem: BasketItem) {
            orderInformation.cartItems.value = orderInformation.cartItems.value.plus(basketItem)
            
        }
}
```

my first screen which adds items to the cart and working well.

```
@Destination
@Composable
fun ShopScreen(
    vm: CartVM = hiltViewModel(),
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator? = null,
) {
  val item = generateRandomItem();

  Button(onClick= {vm.addItemToCart(item)}){Text(text="add to cart")}

  Button(
                       
                        onClick = {
                             //continue to cart
                            navigator?.navigate(CartScreenDestination)
                        },
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Go To Cart",
                            modifier =
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }

}
```

now when you click continue, it  navigates to the following screen but the cart is empty.

```
@Composable
fun CartScreen(
    vm: CartVM = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: DestinationsNavigator,
) {
  

    val cartItems = vm.getAllCartItems()

}
```

but cartItems is empty now. How come it doesn't maintain its list. The composables are under one roof with

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application() {}
```

What am i doing wrong? I thought @HiltViewModel makes the view model singleton and as long as i do CartVM: hiltViewModel(), i would get the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@HiltViewModel` does not making singletons, it's only help Hilt identify viewModels for injection, so you are making two instances of CartVM. Hilt has `Singleton` annotation, but it's not applyable for viewModels. You have 2 options on how to solve it.

**1. create one instance and share it through the screens**

Sorry, i can't make example code because i don't know the navigation you are using.

**2. Create singleton repository for holding data**

ViewModel instances can share singleton repository where you will keep your data.

```
@Singleton
class CartRepo @Inject constructor() {
var orderInformation: OrderInformation by mutableStateOf(OrderInformation())
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CartVM @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

@Inject
lateinit var cartRepo: CartRepo

    fun getAllCartItems(): List<BasketItem> {
    return cartRepo.orderInformation.cartItems.value
    }

    fun addItemToCart(basketItem: BasketItem) {
    cartRepo.orderInformation.cartItems.value =
        cartRepo.orderInformation.cartItems.value.plus(basketItem)

    }
}
```